# Convert list of dictionaries to csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries of this kind :

```
[
{'site1':'data1'},
{'site2':'data2'}
]
```

What would be the proper way to generate a csv file with the data in this order ? :

```
row 1      row2
site1      data1
site2      data2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick :)

```
data = [ {'site1':'data1'}, {'site2':'data2'} ]

with open ('list.csv', 'w') as f:
    for dict in data:
        for key, value in dict.items():
            text = key+','+value+'\n'
            f.writelines(text)
```

Comment: This assumes that the data does not contain commas, quotes or line breaks. Mostly harmless, but CSV lines should end with a `\r\n`. If the data is guaranteed not to have these special characters, this works. But it is not a good general purpose solution.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the dictionaries and write them to the file.

```
list_of_dicts = [{'site1':'data1'},{'site2':'data2'}]
with open('sites.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write('row1\trow2\n')
    for dictionary in list_of_dicts:
         file.write('\t'.join(list(dictionary.items())[0]) + '\n')
```

output:

```
row1    row2
site1   data1
site2   data2
```

---

Note that this requires each dictionary to only have one entry in it, if it has more, one is randomly selected and the others are ignored. There are many different ways to handle their being more than one entry in the dictionaries, so you must add the expected behaviour to the question statement for those cases to be accommodated for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a CSV writer to make sure that any embedded metacharacters such as commas and quotes are escaped properly otherwise data such as `{'site3':'data, data and more data'}` will corrupt the file.

```
import csv

my_list = [{'site1':'data1'}, {'site2':'data2'}]

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_fp:
    writer = csv.writer(out_fp)
    for d in my_list:
        writer.writerows(d.items())
```

You could shorten that up a bit with `itertools` if you want

```
import itertools

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_fp:
    csv.writer(out_fp).writerows(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        d.items() for d in my_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `pandas`'s dataframe to make my data and write them into csv files

```
a = [{'site1':'data1'},{'site2':'data2'}]
#Get each key and values from each dictionaries in the list
keys = []
vals = []
for a1 in a:
    for k, v in a1.items():
        keys.append(k)
        vals.append(v)
#make the dataframe from the keys and values
result = pd.DataFrame({'row1': keys, 'row2':vals})
#write the data into csv, use index=False to not write the row numbers
result.to_csv("mydata.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: An alternative way to construct the `DataFrame` is `pd.DataFrame([i for a1 in a for i in a1.items()], columns=['row1', 'row2'])`